# Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am getting the following error on the word "join" in the code below.

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

```
var organisationQuery = ClientDBContext.Organisations.Where(x => true);

var orderGrouped = from order in ClientDBContext.Orders.Where(x => true)
group order by order.OrganisationId into grouping
select new { Id = grouping.Key.Value, OrderCount = grouping.Count() };

var orders = from og in orderGrouped
join org in organisationQuery on og.Id equals org.Id
select(x => new OrganisationOrdersReportPoco()
{
    OrganisationNameThenCode = org.Name,
    TotalOrders = og.OrderCount
});
```

I don't see a problem with the join clause? Can anyone please advise?

Edit:
This is the piece of SQL I am attempting to write as LINQ.

```
SELECT grp.OrganisationId,
       grp.OrderCount,
       organisations.Name
FROM   (select OrganisationId,
               count(*) as OrderCount
        from orders where 1 = 1 group by OrganisationId) grp
LEFT OUTER JOIN organisations on grp.OrganisationId = organisations.OrganisationId
WHERE 1 = 1
```

I have complicated where clauses on both orders and organisations... simplified for this example.

Comment: Where is the `organisationQuery `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Credit to Giorgi Nakeuri)

I was confusing LAMBDA with LINQ expressions.

Replacing my select with this solved it.

```
select new OrganisationOrdersReportPoco()
{
    OrganisationNameThenCode = org.Name,
    TotalOrders = og.OrderCount
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting into an anonymous type in the first query:

```
var orderGrouped = ..
    select new { Id = grouping.Key.Value, OrderCount = grouping.Count() };
```

This 'breaks' the connection with `order`.

The `join` looks like it should work for Linq-to-Objects but it can't be converted into SQL.

You'll have to eliminate the anonymous type and somehow make a more direct connection.

I wonder why you don't simply go from Organisations? With a proper mapping using nav-properties it should look like:

```
from org in ClientDBContext.Organisations
select(x => new OrganisationOrdersReportPoco()
{
    OrganisationNameThenCode = org.Name,
    TotalOrders = org.Orders.Count
};
```

using the Id properties should be a little more involved but follow the same pattern.

Comment: The how can I join to organisation from the result of a group by of order, like this?

Comment: Try to imagine how this should be converted into SQL. `orderGrouped` can't be related to a Table anymore.

Comment: I need to apply a bespoke where clause to orders so that suggestion wouldnt work. ClientDBContext.Orders has where clauses that aren't shown here... as does organisationQuery. (I tried to simplify the query before posting.)

Comment: code in comments is not readable. But orderGrouped is a bunch of anon tuples, how to know that's from Orders?